# In bash shell, how to insert the previous line inside the current line?

Tags: bash

In bash, how to expand the `!!` in command line while interactively editing the command inside shell? I am working in `vi` edit mode.

When typing a new command line, I want to introduce the previous line and expand it.

**I would like the expansion to occur before I execute the command.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to use <kbd>Alt-^</kbd> in emacs mode (it's similar to <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-e</kbd>, but it should do *only* history expansion).

If it doesn't work for you (for example, there's no default binding for history expansion in vi mode), you can add the binding manually by placing

```
bind '"\e^": history-expand-line'
```

somewhere in your .bashrc, or

```
"\e^": history-expand-line
```

in your .inputrc

**UPDATE.** A couple of remarks:

1. if everything is ok, you should be able to press <kbd>Alt-^</kbd> to substitute any `!!` sequence with your previous command, for example `echo "!!"` would become `echo "previous_command with args"`
2. if it doesn't work as desired, you can check the binding with `bind -P | grep history-expand` (it should return something like `history-expand-line can be found on "\e^"`)

Comment: It works only when the cursor is at the beginning of the line. It's quite a limitation for me.

Comment: It really shouldn't depend on cursor position and it doesn't depend for me. Are you talking about emacs mode or vi mode? Did you add the binding manually or use default one?

Comment: I use vi mode. `Alt-_` works and expand to last args of previous command. But `Alt-^` doesn't do anything

Comment: @YehonathanSharvit Did you try to define *custom* key binding with `bind '"\e^": history-expand-line'`? Just execute this command in your command line and after this you should be able to use `Alt-^` to expand `!!` or `!$` or any other !-sequences. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: No it doesn't work. (I am on ubuntu 11.04)

Comment: And what does `bind -P | grep history-expand` tell to you?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7981/discussion-between-yehonathan-sharvit-and-alexis)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
echo abc
!!
```

Now type Ctrl-Alt-e at the same time (or in emacs parlance C-M-e).

```
echo abc
```

Comment: Not relevant because I would like the expansion to occur before I execute the command

Comment: C-M-e expands but does not execute. You must type return afterwards. I'm not sure I understand your question? If you want to see the last command just type `Ctrl-p`

Comment: I want to insert the previous line while editing the current line and after inserting the previous line, I want to continue editing the current line.

Comment: @YehonathanSharvit Ctrl-Alt-e should do exactly what you described. But it doesn't work in vi mode and it may expand more then you want (it does history, alias and word expansions)

Answer (score 1):

This would make `M-,` insert the previous line in emacs mode:

```
"\e,": "!!\e^"
```

You can also make space expand designators like `!!` by binding it to `magic-space`:

```
" ": magic-space
```